# How to get List View for objects in apex?

Tags: apex, metadata-api

The requirements are:

1. get all of listviews for objects.
2. can filter each objects.

For example, I want to get a `map<String objectName, MetadataObject[]>`

```
map.put('permit2__c', Permit2__c_listView[]);
```

`Permit2__c_listView[]` contains a list of listviews for this object.

Can anyone have some idea or some solution?

Now, I can get a list objects by using metadata API but cannot find the list view in each object. I appreciate that you can provide some solution or code for me.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to retrieve list views via Apex, however have you seen this page in the Metadata API documentation? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_listview.htm

Comment: You will need the ListView Id's (KeyPrefix `00B`) to put on the query string with the `fcf` parameter. At first glance you don't see that ID in the Metadata response. Nor can you see ListView via the Partner or Tooling APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The standardsetcontroller provides a [function](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getListViewOptions.htm) that will return list views, and can [display lists filtered to the list view](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_setFilterID.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this link boss!!!!!!!!!!

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/listview-filter-in-apex-with-paging-and-navigation/

Comment: Hi Tanmay, can you include relevant information from the post? Also there's no need to ask for the answer to be accepted, that's inherant in the site's design.